# pandas moving average by group calculation is wrong

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, moving-average, rolling-computation

My dataframe priceDF begins like this:

```
    Date        symbol  Close
0   2000-01-03  HELN.SW 28.28
1   2000-01-04  HELN.SW 27.50
2   2000-01-05  HELN.SW 26.71
3   2000-01-06  HELN.SW 27.16
4   2000-01-07  HELN.SW 27.50
```

To calculate the moving average of the Closes, grouped by symbol I did:

`priceDF['avg'] = priceDF.groupby('symbol')'Close'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(drop=True)`

and I get:

```
    Date        symbol  Close   avg
0   2000-01-03  HELN.SW 28.28   NaN
1   2000-01-04  HELN.SW 27.50   NaN
2   2000-01-05  HELN.SW 26.71   12.537398
3   2000-01-06  HELN.SW 27.16   12.022164
4   2000-01-07  HELN.SW 27.50   11.922733
```

In row 2, I want avg = 27.50, the average of the Closes in rows 0 to 2.
What do I misunderstand?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem, i.e. I get the right numbers. There is a small syntax error in you code but assume it is a copy and paste problem not the actual code (as it would not run as written). Check your pandas version? see what the calc does without assignment (eg run just this part `priceDF.groupby('symbol')['Close'].rolling(3).mean()` see if the numbers make sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is an issue with how `reset_index` is used here,in conjuction with having multiple groups.  Let us consider a slightly extended example:

```
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(
'''
   Date        symbol  Close
0   2000-01-03  HELN.SW 28.28
1   2000-01-04  HELN.SW 27.50
2   2000-01-05  HELN.SW 26.71
3   2000-01-06  HELN.SW 27.16
4   2000-01-07  HELN.SW 27.50
5   2000-01-07  AAAA.SW 30.00
''')
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep = '\s+', index_col=0)
```

(we have added AAAA.SW to the list)

Now this:

```
df.groupby('symbol')['Close'].rolling(3).mean()
```

produces sensible numbers (as there is only one date for AAAA we expect NaN:

```
symbol    
AAAA.SW  5          NaN
HELN.SW  0          NaN
         1          NaN
         2    27.496667
         3    27.123333
         4    27.123333
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

but this:

```
df.groupby('symbol')['Close'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(drop=True)
```

produces wrong indices

```
0          NaN
1          NaN
2          NaN
3    27.496667
4    27.123333
5    27.123333
Name: Close, dtype: float64
```

and when put into the original df end up in the wrong rows:

```
df['avg'] = df.groupby('symbol')['Close'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

produces

```
     Date       symbol  Close   avg
0   2000-01-03  HELN.SW 28.28   NaN
1   2000-01-04  HELN.SW 27.50   NaN
2   2000-01-05  HELN.SW 26.71   NaN
3   2000-01-06  HELN.SW 27.16   27.496667
4   2000-01-07  HELN.SW 27.50   27.123333
5   2000-01-07  AAAA.SW 30.00   27.123333
```

a solution is to do the aqssignments within each group, like this:

```
df.groupby('symbol').apply(lambda g: g.assign(avg = g['Close'].rolling(3).mean())).reset_index(drop=True)
```

so we get

```
    Date        symbol  Close   avg
0   2000-01-07  AAAA.SW 30.00   NaN
1   2000-01-03  HELN.SW 28.28   NaN
2   2000-01-04  HELN.SW 27.50   NaN
3   2000-01-05  HELN.SW 26.71   27.496667
4   2000-01-06  HELN.SW 27.16   27.123333
5   2000-01-07  HELN.SW 27.50   27.123333
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, piterbarg for your elaborate answer and a correct solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, piterbarg for your elaborate answer. Now, I understand my error. The assignment priceDF["avg"]=... was a bad idea, because groupby returns values sorted by symbol. HELN.SW is the first symbol from many in the original dataframe. The first symbol returned from groupby is 0012.HK. So, I joined the moving averages of 0012.HK to HELN.SW. After applying your code, the resulting dataframe begins like this '''  Date symbol Close avg
0 2000-01-04 0012.HK 13.450359 NaN
1 2000-01-05 0012.HK 12.474124 NaN
2 2000-01-06 0012.HK 11.687712 12.53
3 2000-01-07 0012.HK 11.904655 12.02'''